# Is it possible to have an array containing HashMap keys?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

yeah, basically can you add HashMap keys to arrays?

For example, could I have a String array containing these String HashMap keys?

```
HashMap container = new HashMap();
container.put("A", 1);
container.put("B", 2);
container.put("C", 5);
container.put("D", 8);
```

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want a `new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D"}`?

Comment: Yes you could. Take a look at `HashMap#keySet` and `#toArray`

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis i need an array that references the HashMap keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
container.keySet().toArray()
```

will give you a Object[]

```
"A", "D", "B", "C"
```

The order is undefined.

Note that even with HashMap, keySet() will return Set but toArray() will still be Object[] and therefore needs to be casted:

```
String[] keys = (String[]) container.keySet().toArray();
```

or:

```
String[] keys = container.keySet().toArray(new String[container.keySet().size()]);
```

(you can do `new String[0]` but it's less efficient as it will reallocate the array, so it's better to do it right upfront)

Comment: Hmm. thanks for the answer. I definitely need the Array to be a String Array.

would it be possible to create a String out of the HashMap key, then add that new String to Array?

Comment: Create your HashMap with `HashMap<String, Integer> container = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` but you still need to say `String[] keys = (String[]) container.keySet().toArray();`

Comment: i managed to get what i was looking for by swapping the key's and values around and using [code]String personA=(String)container.get(1);[/code]

thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can't cast the result of `toArray()`. You need to use the overloaded method if you want an array of type T.